# How to call view in another view by using cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am just new CakePhp, i wonder how to call a view in another view.

When I started to run CakePhp the default layout is located in **view/layouts/default.ctp**.

In **default.ctp** I called a view name homeview (**view/homes/homeview.ctp**).

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php 
     echo $this->fetch('homeview'); // this statement here is work
?>
```

And in the **homeview.ctp** I called another view named displayphone (**view/homes/displayphone.ctp**)
**homeview.ctp**

```
<?php $this->start('homeview'); ?>
    <h1> This is home view </h1>
    <?php echo $this->fetch('displayphone'); // this statement does not work; ?>
<?php $this->end(); ?>
```

**displayphone.ctp**

```
<?php $this->start('displayphone');?>
    <h1> This page display phone </h1>
<?php $this->end(); ?>
```

Why I can not call displayphone block in homeview ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you mentioned,

```
 $this->fetch('homeview');
```

has created a block by name homeview, Refer this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html

As far as calling another view inside the view is not possible unless you create an element for that. Element are the common set of HTML which can be used in any view file throughout the project. For above purpose create an element by name "displayphone.ctp" in Element folder inside view and then call it like

```
 $this->element('displayphone');
```

Hope this will solve your purpose.

Comment: How to include `ctp`? Both `homeview` and `displayphone` is same directory. i don't need to any changes in place. I don't want to create an `element`

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can call a view inside another view(Not good but you can do it).

For example you have view 2 views
Views/Users/login.ctp
Views/Users/register.ctp

and you want to call register view inside login view.

```
// File login.ctp
$this->Element('../Users/register.ctp'); // ('..' . DS . 'Users' . DS . 'register.ctp')
```

This will get register view as an element and work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to create element
which you can include in any view file.

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 3, use this

```
<?= $this->requestAction('/Users/register') ?>
```