# How can I extend a view in cakePHP?

Tags: php, templates, cakephp

I'm trying to create the most basic extended view possible based on the [cakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#extending-views).
But it's not working and I cannot figure out why.

Parent view:

```
//Pages/home.ctp
<h2>This is a Map </h2>
<?php echo $this->fetch('map','default value: NO MAP EXTENDED D:'); ?>
```

This is the child view:

```
//Locations/View.ctp
<?php
    $this->extend('/Pages/home.ctp');
    $this->start('map');
?>
    <div>
        Hello, I am the map view.
    </div>
<?php $this->end(); ?>
```

I tried extending 'Pages/home', '/Pages/home', and '/Pages/home.ctp'. Neither are working.
The home.ctp page just shows the `<h2>` header and the default value instead of the extended view.

I saw the question [How to call view in another view by using cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354280/how-to-call-view-in-another-view-by-using-cakephp), but based on the book the `$this->extend(...)` function should do this without any extra hassle. What am I missing?

Could someone show a working example?

Comment: What url are you going to, `/Locations/View`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading [the CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html) entry, it seems to be expecting a “common” view stored in somewhere like **app/View/Common/map.ctp** and then your views to extend this. This *should* work in theory then:

```
// app/View/Common/map.ctp
<h1><?php echo $this->fetch('title'); ?></h1>
<?php echo $this->fetch('map'); ?>
```

And then your extending view:

```
<?php
// app/View/Locations/view.ctp
$this->extend('/Common/map');

$this->assign('title', 'Some Title');

$this->start('map');
?>
<div id="map_canvas">
  <p>Hello, world!</p>
</div>
<?php $this->end(); ?>
```

Assuming your controller is called `LocationsController` and method name is `view()`.