# Cloning/Forking a template project as opposed to branching?

Tags: git

I'm not terribly good at git-fu, so I look to the experts.  I have a template webapp, and I would like to create several sites based on this template.  The new sites will rarely if ever push updates back to the template, but I want to be able to capture all updates to the template.

Is it wiser to create branches, or outright clone/forks?
In terms of organization, I would prefer to fork, but with little experience with Git, I'm not positive that this is a good way to go.

What advantages/disadvantages might I see with each method?

Thanks

Comment: What is your intended flow of updates between the projects?

Comment: If I understand the question (and perhaps I don't, ha ha)... I intend to use the template project as a 'starter' for the others.  They will be updated as I develop them, but at times I may realize I need to fix or add a feature to the template that they would all benefit from.  The template project would be updated, and then the updates would be committed to all the other projects.  Again, I apologize if I did not correctly interpret the question, somewhat new to git (beyond a one person, simple project, ha ha).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloning is just a different way of branching, so the discussion isn't really about using one of these methods.

However, I would counter your approach as a whole. You intend to create a central software project that will play a major part in several other projects. While you might be able to manage this with either branching or cloning, I would suggest to not use either. You have several distinct software projects, with one of them being somehow more central to the others.

I would use one repository for the central stuff, at some point tag a version that can be used, and find a way to allow using that version (and any following version) somewhere.

To create the "child" projects, you grab such a released version and add all the customizations on top - but don't stuff the central software into the repository, only a reference to the used version.

This highly depends on which language you are developing in, because it must make use of whatever that language has to offer to integrate a released software package into your child projects. This is a question of dependency managers, and by now every common language should have one.

Another thing to consider: You probably will not start the central project from scratch, you'd probably use plenty of helpful, openly available libraries to get started. These are another layer of dependencies that has to be managed, and stuffing them into the central repository also is not the best idea. Use the same dependency management system here (which depends on the language).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; to be clear, I'm working in PHP, using the CakePHP framework.

The problem here is that my main project is not merely a "dependency;" it's a template.  The files of the template will be modified, which means I need to be able to track changes to both the template and the dependent projects, so that some form of updates can be produced from the template project which could be applied to the child project (not merely replacing files, but modifying files that have been changed).  Am I making any sense?

Comment: Practical simple example:

Child: index.php based on Template: index.php.

Child: index.php gets some updates to let it show a news article.

Template: index.php gets updated because I found an error in my original code.

I would like to be able to push the new Template: index.php code to all the Child projects to update their index.php with the new code (without losing their own changes)

Comment: This will be possible to do with branching/cloning, but be impractical to manage in the long term. By editing that file in your child project, you most likely change the structure of the file. Any change from the parent project has to be merged, which will lead to conflicts the more changes you do in the child's version. Resolving conflicts means you have to know which changes in both versions should do what, and how to put them together manually. Do you remember what you did last summer to a child project, and what you did last fall to the parent project when you now want to update the child?

Comment: That's fair.  I'm hoping there wont be a great number of changes to files modified by the child, but it would happen.  Is there a better solution/is there ANY solution for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You will probably want to avoid pulling changes from the parent into a developed/customized child. This means you can develop the parent project in a repository, and any new child gets created by copying the most recent version of the parent into a new repository and commit it there as the first commit. You'd end up having as many repositories as you have projects, and they all got bootstrapped with the then most current version of the parent. After the initial copy, you don't bother trying to move changes made to the parent into existing projects. If you feel the need, you apply them manually

Comment: That's unfortunate.  I was really hoping to make life a bit easier.  I foresee many reasons to make the updates (new features, bug fixes, security issues, etc).  Well, thanks for your help

Comment: And because I too see that you want to do this, I suggested how to achieve it. And it does NOT move the changes via Git mechanics, but via software architecture.

Comment: I understand (and again, appreciate your feedback); I just see the solution as being particular cumbersome (not that that's your fault; if there's not a good solution, there's just not a good solution).  Imagine 10 different projects, with even a handful of updates to the template, manually updating all those changes would take several hours.

Comment: But what if all that's needed is a template with a .gitignore, .gitattributes, and maybe a few other files that will either be unchanged or changed permanently in one-direction?

Using bitbucket, it would also be cool to copy the repository access and service hooks.

Comment: @xtraOrange I don't see an issue in the template fork as long as you don't do any bad merges from parent to child. But certainly do good merges from parent to child for feature updates, fixes, etc. Merging is what git was built for. Use it for that.

Comment: +1. `Practical simple example…` [in CakePHP templates can be extended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17064264/761202) - that’s one way to have clear separation and still achieve the goal described (in comments).

Answer (score 1):

I want to do something similar, and this question was high in the search results. I'm developing an MS Access database template with code for exporting objects/data (you can't do useful diffs on a monolithic binary file) and updating the user's front-end application. After reading [this article](https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2020/11/30/propagating-git-template-changes.html) and some experimentation, I think it can work. (At least, the article seems to achieve what the OP was trying to do.)

**Disclaimer: This is based on an afternoon of messing about in a tiny sandbox. More advanced users than I may yet offer advice (I hope) or continue to point out that this is a fool's errand.**

First, create your bare template repository. Have a branch named something descriptive (i.e., besides "master" or "trunk" or "main".) There's lots of room for creative branch strategies. I kept it simple and renamed the main branch. (I did all my experiments on the local machine. Do the equivalent on your remote host of choice. "Remote," bare repos are named with title case.)

```
~/Template > git init --bare --initial-branch template
```

Set up your bare project repository. I had some trouble on the project side. `--bare` creates a lot of support files that can be cloned into a fresh working copy. These files get in the way when you're trying to push a different set of fresh support files into an empty repo. If your remote will be created by a push, you'll have to do a regular init there, followed by editing the configuration. You may have to get this working locally and then import the remote to your host (somehow.)

```
~/Project > git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/Project/.git/

~/Project > git config --bool core.bare true
```

Clone the Template repo to a local working copy. Develop the templates and push the changes.

```
~/tmpworking > clone ../Template .
Cloning into '.'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.

~/tmpworking > touch T1 T2

~/tmpworking > git add .

~/tmpworking > git commit -m "Initial template commit."
[template (root-commit) a2116f4] Initial commit.
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 T1
 create mode 100644 T2

~/tmpworking > git push origin
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Delta compression using up to 24 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 217 bytes | 217.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To ~/Template/../template
 * [new branch]      template -> template
```

Start your project's working copy by cloning the template.

```
~/ > git clone Template working
Cloning into 'working'...
done.
```

To streamline the workflow, change the template branch's remote reference from "origin" so the main project can use it. You will want to change the name of the branch too. In this example, "template" is the name of the remote connection for pulling changes, and "tmp" is the name of the branch these changes are pulled to. Later, the trunk branch will merge changes from tmp. (Whether this is more or less confusing is left to the reader. Do as you like.)

```
~/working > git remote rename origin template
Renaming remote references: 100% (3/3), done.

~/working > git remote -v
template        ../Template (fetch)
template        ../Template (push)

~/working > git branch -m template tmp
```

The article makes a big deal of not pushing template changes from your project. This may be overkill, but it forces changes to the template to originate from working files specifically checked out from that repository and for that purpose. In this example, the templates get edits from `~/tmpworking`. The project enforces this by changing the remote path to an invalid value.

```
~/working > git remote set-url --push template no_push

~/working > git remote -v
template        ../Template (fetch)
template        no_push (push)

~/working > git log
commit 2eef44bdfae039635df56bc363914582bf4380e0 (HEAD -> tmp, template/template, template/HEAD)
Author: Jim <jim@email.com>
Date:   Sat Mar 4 03:31:33 2023 -0700

    Initial template commit.
```

Now we start the project from the templates. Create the main branch and switch to it. Then change the remote for the branch.

```
~/working > git branch trunk

~/working > git switch trunk
Switched to branch 'trunk'

~/working > ls
T1  T2
```

Now, set up the remote path for the project, and push the raw templates to the project as a baseline while setting the trunk's upstream path.

```
~/working > git remote add origin ../Project

~/working > git remote -v
origin  ../Project (fetch)
origin  ../Project (push)
template        ../Template (fetch)
template        no_push (push)

~/working >  git push --set-upstream origin trunk
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Delta compression using up to 24 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 217 bytes | 217.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To ../Project
 * [new branch]      trunk -> trunk
branch 'trunk' set up to track 'origin/trunk'.
```

Your project is set up with its templates and ready to push changes to its repo.

```
~/working > touch P1

~/working > git add P1

~/working >  git commit -m "Initial project commit with templates."
[trunk f222d3c] Initial project commit with templates.
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 P1

~/working > git push origin trunk
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Delta compression using up to 24 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 256 bytes | 256.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To ../Project
   a2116f4..f222d3c  trunk -> trunk
```

When there are updates to the template, switch to the tmp branch and pull the changes. Then, switch back to trunk (or whatever intermediary you like) and merge the changes from tmp.

In time, the graph of changes will start to look like this (the project changes are on the left path):

```
~/working > git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
*   cda1c24 (HEAD -> trunk) Merge updates from the template.
|\
| * 9718ee1 (template/template, template/HEAD, tmp) Gave T2 some love.
| * 58d6be6 Expanded line 3. Tweaked line 7.
* | 179eadd (origin/trunk) That seems to work ok. I'm sure nothing bad will happen in the future.
|\|
| * 5e3d3a2 Getting really useful.
* | 79a4d51 Resolved new feature around custom changes.
|\|
| * 24b565b Added more features.
* | 7e83f18 Custom mod to T1
* | 90d5702 P1 is coming along nicely.
* | 1b39d5b Merge template updates to trunk.
|\|
| * 7a5bb5d Fixed typos in T1.
| * 0400565 Added functionality to T1.
* | b067b46 Initial project commit with templates.
|/
* 2eef44b Initial template commit.
```

I assume that changes to templates on the main project line (if such things are even allowed) are not supposed to infect the original templates. That's why we fouled the tmp branch's push reference. You may want to look into setting up a pre-merge-commit hook to prevent changes in the main line from flowing back into the tmp branch. I'm also not sure how difficult merges may become if they have to weave into main-line changes. (7e83f18 was such a change, and the merge went ok. Hence, the message for 179eadd.) This is where the experts could chime in and save us from our folly.

I hope someone finds this useful.